# Aptana Studio selected text is hard to read regardless of theme

Tags: text, aptana, selection, highlighting

I'm running into trouble in Aptana Studio in regard to selected text. It seems that regardless of the theme I select, the foreground color is the same as the background color, rendering the text close to invisible. I've tried changing a few color settings, turning off occurrences, and I've noticed when I change the theme for a split second I'll see the text perfectly clear. It happens too quick for me to screenshot, though, and the text goes back to being nearly invisible right away. Below are some pictures of the problem.

Anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Invisible text no matter the theme.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aptana has a problem when changing theme.

Choose your theme then restart Aptana and it will load fine.

Comment: Had to apply the theme settings from the preferences panel instead of from the theme toolbar menu, but doing that and restarting worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just to note, this was actually a bug which should be fixed in the latest nightly and should be available in the next release. See: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4895

Answer (score 1):

The tip I posted in the my comment above has worked; since I made that change, this problem has gone away. You don't say you're using PyDev, but I'll guess that you are since the screenshots are Python.

I'm using PyDev in Aptana.

There is a setting PyDev -> Editor :Use aptana themes?

I turned it off, restarted, and the problem has not re-occurred. I was using the PyDev theme prior to disabling this, and those settings continue to apply.

Comment: Good tip. Tried it, and the highlighting is working correctly! The only problem is that without customization, [it has problems with dark themes.](http://content.screencast.com/users/zshall/folders/Jing/media/ff32a200-76c1-49b0-872f-4472683e1504/2012-06-29_1156.png). Of course, you could change the Pydev colors manually, but it isn't as flexible as the restart trick.